# howto get the event when someone press the back key and get in a xaml site in wp7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, navigation

how can i get the event when the user is on page A and go to page B. on page B he press back and returns tu page A.
need to determin when this happen, how could i do this with wp7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnNavigatedTo event that handles navigation to a page, be it by NavigationService's Navigate or GoBack method, have no event information on from which page you navigated from, and neither about how you navigated.

So in short: It's not possible. And I can't imagine any good reason for it either.

Answer (score 1):

There is [PhoneApplicationPage.OnBackKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.onbackkeypress%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) that does exactly the job you are looking for.

Comment: no, this event is fired on page B but i need a event that comes up on page A when it was startet via the back button

Comment: OnNavigatedTo is your only choice here. There is no way the first page will know about the back button press unless you have a global state indicator that will be checked when the first page is loaded.